# Browser randomly deleting cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, cookies

I'm using cookies to manage authentication in a React app. There are two instances where the browser cookies get deleted client side. What could be causing this?

EDIT: This only seems to be happening with Firefox Developer Edition. It works as expected in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Not sure what they're doing differently...

#### Fetching assets from an express server

(1) User clicks a link, which triggers a fetch to download a file from an express server. I download the file. When I click the same link again, the cookie disappears from the browser and fails the download a second time.

client fetching the asset

```js
async function promptDownload(fetchResponse, filename) {
  const blob = await fetchResponse.blob();
  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = fileURL;
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.download = filename;
  a.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
}

export const fetchAsset = async (url, filename, jwt) => {
  try {
    var fetchResponse = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  promptDownload(fetchResponse, filename);
};
```

nodejs serving the asset:

```js
app.get("/assets/:filename", (req, res) => {
  res.download(file);
});
```

#### Navigating the website (expiry issue?)

(2) Browser randomly deletes the cookie as the user is navigating the website. I set the cookie expiry to 15 min - I've tested a few times, but every now and then it deletes the cookie before those 15 mins are up. The cookie only gets deleted when the user changes routes (I'm making an async call to get a new cookie at every route change).

What are some common instances that could cause a cookie to be deleted, other than expiry and closing the browser?

Comment: Is the time on the server correct?

Comment: @Evert Good point, I didn't check that. But I used "max-age" (instead of "expires") to set the cookie expiry, so would that matter in this case?

Comment: Browsers might still consider the `Date` field as a base time to calculate the expiry time from.

Comment: Checked the timestamp, looks good :/